# Plotting Contours of Lat/Lon Based Values

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation, contour

I am attempting to plot weather variables on a map of Oklahoma using mpl_toolkits.basemap, but am having issues figuring out how to interpolate the data to plot on top of the map.

Here is a general idea of the current code I have:

```
lons = [-97.9547, -97.9747, -97.4256]
lats = [35.5322, 35.864, 35.4111]
data = [2,2,2]
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon = -103.068237, llcrnrlat = 33.610045, urcrnrlon = -94.359076, urcrnrlat = 37.040928, resolution = 'i')  


CS = map.contour(X, Y, data)
map.drawstates()
plt.show()
```

What I am attempting to accomplish is to plot the data values on the map based on the related reference index in the lons/lats lists, and then contour the values of the data variable.

Now this obviously won't work, because I need to interpolate the data.  Is there a way that I could accomplish this using the griddata function?  I am very confused on how I would establish the boundaries of the grid given that latitude and longitude values are not linearly spaced.

Is there an easier way to do this that I am missing?

Any help and/or hints would be greatly appreciated, this is holding me back from moving on to the next major portion of the research project!

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use something like [meshgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html). Then you need to interpolate your data onto the mesh that you `lons` and `lats` create.

Comment: From what I understand, meshgrid will only work for data that does not need interpolation, e.g. data already set up to where it will work in square coordinates.

Comment: meshgrid just creates the grid onto which you interpolate whatever data you want. If you give it two arrays to create the grid from which have all of the coordinates you want already, you won't need to do any interpolation...

Comment: Thank you so much, Will.  I had looked over the meshgrid function yesterday but apparently either misinterpreted it or had a brain fart.  I have it all figured out, now, thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have python installed on this machine, so can't test this. But something like this should get you the required inputs for the countour plot...

```
import numpy as np

lons = [-97.9547, -97.9747, -97.4256]
lats = [35.5322, 35.864, 35.4111]
data = [2,2,2]

xs, ys = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

dataMesh = np.empty_like(xs)
for i, j, d in zip(lons, lats, data):
    dataMesh[lons.index(i), lats.index(j)] = d

map = Basemap(llcrnrlon = -103.068237, llcrnrlat = 33.610045, urcrnrlon = -94.359076, urcrnrlat = 37.040928, resolution = 'i')  


CS = map.contour(xs, ys, dataMesh)
map.drawstates()
plt.show()
```

Like i said though, i haven't tested this. I don't know what happens if you try to plot unititialised values. you might need to use a different numpy array initialisation.

Comment: This should not work! Look, you have 3 Datapoints and generates a matrix (meshgrid) with 9 data points. So where do you get the 6 values from?

Comment: @dl.meteo I don't think that's the real data, just an example of the form they have it in.